# html - trigger event if mouse clicked for few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know how to do this.

I need to trigger an event when I clicked over a link for 2-3 seconds. if it's less than 1 second then it does not do anything.

I hope I got my message across.

Comment: use JS. settimeout() is the method you need to use. search for that

Comment: High level: trigger an event when the mouse button is pressed, start a timer, when the timer expired check if the mouse is still pressed down.

Comment: look up mousedown and mouseup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can use *timers* to achieve this:

```
var pressTimer

$("a").mouseup(function(){
  clearTimeout(pressTimer)
  // Clear timeout
  return false;
}).mousedown(function(){
  // Set timeout
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { ... your code ...},1000)
  return false; 
});
```

See if this works for you! :)

Comment: was just about to suggest a mousedown/mouseup trigger haha

Comment: What if the computer lags before the mouse is released after less than one second (this one might not be possible to fix)?

Comment: @JanDvorak To an extent we can handle. For now, I just suggested this. Yeah, we can improve on it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer;
$(function(){
    $('#ele').mousedown(function(){
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
           timer = '';
        },1000);
    }).mouseup(function(){
        if(timer != ''){
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @JanDvorak I think `undefined` would be correct in this situation (unless `timer` was set as `null` at the start), or even using `!isNaN(timer)` because `setTimeout` actually returns an integer